# Snap store and gnome software using a ton of RAM

Tags: gnome, snap, 22.10, gnome-software, snap-store

Snap Store and Gnome-Software use 1.5GB and 1.4GB respectively, is this normal?
If I kill the process and restart, they seem to hover at around ~700MB each, mind you the ~1.5GB is on startup.

Is this normal, and also how can I disable them from startup applications considering they're not on the list of startup applications?

[image]

Comment: Something is definitely amiss. When I run snap-store it takes up ~45MB initially and increases to ~60MB when I installed a new app.

Answer (score 1):

Most software that autostarts on login is located in the directory `/etc/xdg/autostart/`.
You can delete or move any `.desktop` shortcut that you don't want auto-starting.

To disable `Gnome Software` autostart, you could also copy `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-software-service.desktop` to `~/.config/autostart` and append `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` to the end of the file.